# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: duplicates value on record with id: : []

Tags: apex

```
 //method to create an Event
@AuraEnabled
public Static String saveEvent(String listEveWrp,List<Id> listCon,id userId, String eventRecordId){
    try{
        Set<String> setConIds = new Set<String>();
        for(Id con : listCon){
            setConIds.add(con);
        }
        List<String> params = listEveWrp.split('::');
        Event eve = new Event();
        Task newTask = new Task();
        String contactId = params[0] != null && params[0] !='' && params[0] != 'undefined' ? params[0] : null;
        eve.WhoId = contactId;
        eve.Subject = params[1];
        Date dt = date.valueOf(params[3]);
        //Updated by Thimmaiah
        //User Story 240554: Handling error of ICU components
        //Updated Date.Parse() with Date.newInstance() to handle salesforce ICU update
        List<String> startTimeLst = params[2].split(' ');
        List<String> start_hr_min = startTimeLst[0].split(':');
        Integer startHr = startTimeLst[1] == 'PM' && start_hr_min[0] != '12' ? Integer.valueOf(start_hr_min[0]) +12 : Integer.valueOf(start_hr_min[0]);
        Integer startMin = Integer.valueOf(start_hr_min[1]);
        Time startTime = Time.newInstance(startHr, startMin, 0, 0) ;
        eve.StartDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(dt, startTime);
        system.debug('StartDateTime :'+eve.StartDateTime+' *** '+dt + ' *** '+startTime);
        //system.debug('Parse :'+DateTime.parse(strtDt+' '+params[2]));
        Date dt1 = date.valueOf(params[5]);
        List<String> endTimeLst = params[4].split(' ');
        List<String> end_hr_min = endTimeLst[0].split(':');
        Integer endHr = endTimeLst[1] == 'PM' && end_hr_min[0] != '12' ? Integer.valueOf(end_hr_min[0]) +12 : Integer.valueOf(end_hr_min[0]);
        Integer endMin = Integer.valueOf(end_hr_min[1]);
        Time endTime = Time.newInstance(endHr, endMin, 0, 0) ;
        eve.EndDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(dt1, endTime);
        system.debug('EndDateTime :'+eve.EndDateTime+' *** '+dt1 + ' *** '+endTime);
        eve.OwnerId = (params[11] != null && params[11] != '' && params[11] != 'undefined') ? params[11] : userId;
        eve.IsAllDayEvent = params[6] == 'true' ? true : false;
        eve.Location = (params[7] != null && params[7] != '' && params[7] != 'undefined') ? params[7] : '';
        eve.Description = (params[8] != null && params[8] != '' && params[8] != 'undefined') ? params[8] : '';
        // IsPrivate not used anymore
        //eve.IsPrivate = params[9] == 'true' ? true : false;
        eve.ShowAs = params[10]!= '--None--'? params[10] : '';
        eve.Reason__c=params[12]==''||params[12]==null||params[12]=='undefined'? ' ':params[12];
        //Added for Story 88719
        eve.In_Person__c= params[13] == 'true' ? true : false;
        eve.Virtual__c= params[14] == 'true' ? true : false;
        eve.Event_Subject__c = params[1];
        eve.Event_Type__c= params[15];
        eve.Event_Sub_type__c= params[16]!= '--None--'? params[16] : '';
        eve.Create_Follow_Up_Task__c= params[17] == 'true' ? true : false;
        
        
        if(params[18] != '--None--'){
            params[18]= params[18].replace(',',';');
            eve.Event_Subtype_Multipicklist__c=params[18];
        }else{
            eve.Event_Subtype_Multipicklist__c='';
        }
        
        
        if(eve.Create_Follow_Up_Task__c){
            Date dt3 = date.valueOf(params[19]);
            String folloupDate = dt3.month()+ '/' +dt3.day()+ '/' +dt3.year();    
            eve.Follow_up_date__c = Date.parse(folloupDate);
        }else{
            eve.Follow_up_date__c = null;
        }
        
        //Added for Story 88719
        
        if(eventRecordId != ''){
            eve.id=eventRecordId;
            // List<EventRelation> eventRelationList = [Select id,RelationId from EventRelation where eventId = : eventRecordId and RelationId != :contactId];
            // Delete eventRelationList;
            /*
            for(EventRelation er : eventRelationList){
                setConIds.remove(er.RelationId);
            }
            */
        }
        
        //insert eve;
        upsert eve;
        
        //added on 09/23 to skip insert for edit flow
        if(eve.Create_Follow_Up_Task__c && eventRecordId == ''){
            //newTask.ActivityDate = System.Today() + 3;
            if(eve.Follow_up_date__c != null){
                newTask.ActivityDate = eve.Follow_up_date__c;
            }else{
                newTask.ActivityDate = System.Today() + 3;
            }
            newTask.Description=eve.Description;
            newTask.OwnerId=eve.OwnerId;
            newTask.Parent_Task__c=eve.Id;
            newTask.Status='In Progress';
            newTask.Subject='Follow up on '+eve.Event_Subject__c;
            newTask.whoId=eve.whoId;
            insert newTask;
        }
        
        setConIds.remove(contactId);
        system.debug('=== contactId'+ contactId);
        List<EventRelation> listER = new List<EventRelation>();
        List<TaskRelation> listTaskRelation = new List<TaskRelation>();
        for(String conId : setConIds){
            EventRelation er = new EventRelation();
            er.eventId = eve.Id;
            er.isParent = true;
            er.RelationId = conId;
            listER.add(er);
        }
        Insert listER;           <----------> here is the error
        system.debug('===listER  ' + listER);
        system.debug('===listER.size()  '+ listER.size());
        
        //added on 09/23 to skip insert for edit flow
        if(eve.Create_Follow_Up_Task__c && eventRecordId == ''){
            for(String conId : setConIds){
                TaskRelation tr = new TaskRelation();
                tr.taskId = newTask.Id;
                tr.RelationId = conId;
                listTaskRelation.add(tr);
            }
            insert listTaskRelation;  
            system.debug('=== listTaskRelation' + listTaskRelation);
        }
        
        return 'Success';
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, e.getLineNumber() + ' :: '+ e);
        new LogException().log(e);
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here we are trying to create an event, on a contact. I can create a new event, or delete an older event and add the event again. Have some required fields, when i try to edit and update the data getting the error.
I can use database.insert(listER,false); on the line, but is there anyway other way?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting indicates that the same combination of eventId and relationId already exists in the database. I.e. the relationship already exists.

The best practice is to not do any DML if it's not needed.

I.e. query the EventRelation table for any relationId's in your setConIds. Then if any combination of eventId and relationId already exists, skip the creation of a new EventRelation.

You might be able to define from the context if EventRelation creation will ever be necessary. E.g. if this is triggered from an Event update, and the Contact is not changed, then you can skip this part of your code entirely.